# Jbuilder: How I can merge 2 top level arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, jbuilder

I have two top level arrays, which have the same format. And I want to merge them:

```
json = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.(companies) do |json, c|
    json.value c.to_s
    json.href employee_company_path(c)
  end
  json.(company_people) do |json, cp|
    json.value "#{cp.to_s} (#{cp.company.to_s})"
    json.href employee_company_path(cp.company)
  end
end
```

So the output would be as follows: `"[{value: "a", href: "/sample1"}, {value: "b", href: "/sample2"}]"`

But the code above doesn't work. It includes only the second array: `"[{value: "b", href: "/sample2"}]"`

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
result =  []
companies.each do |c|
  result << {:value => c.to_s, :href => employee_company_path(c)
end
company_people.each do |c|
  result << {:value => "#{cp.to_s} (#{cp.company.to_s})", :href => employee_company_path(cp.company)
end
# at this point result will be an array of companies and people which just needs converting to json.
result.to_json
```

Comment: I was looking for something more "Jbuilder like solution", but this is also good. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I know of two options:

1. Combine the arrays before iterating, which works well with multiple source arrays of ducks:

   ```
   def Employee
     def company_path
       self.company.company_path if self.company
     end
   end

   [...]

   combined = (companies + company_people).sort_by{ |c| c.value }
   # Do other things with combined

   json.array!(combined) do |duck|
     json.value(duck.to_s)
     json.href(duck.company_path)
   end
   ```
2. Or when you've got ducks and turkeys, combine the json arrays:

   ```
   company_json = json.array!(companies) do |company|
     json.value(company.to_s)
     json.href(employee_company_path(company))
   end

   people_json = json.array!(company_people) do |person|
     json.value(person.to_s)
     json.href(employee_company_path(person.company))
   end

   company_json + people_json
   ```

In both cases, there's no need to call #to_json or similar.

Comment: How could I combine and sort those array by value, and add a key to them?

Comment: @PeterR In the first example, the two arrays are being combined. To operate further on them—without making the code hard to read—pull the combination out of the #array! call and do what you like. I expanded the example to show one way that might work out.

Answer (score 3):

Yuri's answer got me close, but the ultimate solution for me was simply doing this in my `.jbuilder` file.

```
json.array!(companies) do |company|
  json.value(company.to_s)
  json.href(employee_company_path(company))
end

json.array!(company_people) do |person|
  json.value(person.to_s)
  json.href(employee_company_path(person.company))
end
```

The order I put the arrays in is the order the array was combined.